# Dúvida sobre lógica gerenciamento de itens em um e-commerce

Tags: e-commerce

Olá,
Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de e-commerce e tenho a seguinte dúvida sobre gerenciamento de itens:

Quando uma transação é efetivada (dada como paga) pelo gateway de pagamento, o **usuário administrador** é o responsável pelo decremento da quantidade de itens ou essa responsabilidade é do próprio sistema?

Comment: Você que decide. Geralmente é o próprio sistema para evitar trabalho braçal.

Comment: Em questão de estoque no sistema, o produto deve (em teoria) ser decrementado no momento que dá a sua saída, ou seja, no momento em que ele foi despachado. Porém, é necessário que haja também uma sinalização que este produto (esta unidade em questão) não esteja mais disponível para venda. Analisando isso, você chegará numa decisão. :) Espero ter ajudado.